# Does the order of the letters R and F in rm -rf (-rf -fr) matters?

Tags: cron, getopt, rm

I have a website that uses a Cron to execute a few Unix command line codes to clean some `PHP` cache.

```
rm -rf path/to/cache/folder/*
```

In `rm` I know that:

- `-r` stands for **recursive**
- `-f` stands for **force**

But does the order changes the meaning?

Comment: What does SSH have to do with this?

Comment: Exclude subdirectories of a folder, like : `rm -rf path/to/folder/*`

Comment: That still does not involve SSH.

Comment: You should take a look on this to understand my side: http://dustyreagan.com/how-to-delete-an-entire-directory-via-ssh/

Comment: It will matter if `-f` is meant for `ssh` or meant for `rm`. These 2 commands differ, `ssh -f user@host rm -r /path` as opposed to `ssh user@host rm -f -r /path`. The 1st one forces `ssh` to go background before recursively deleting `/path` while the latter forces `rm` to recursively delete `/path`.

Comment: So `ssh user@host rm -f -r /path` == `ssh user@host rm -r -f /path`?

Comment: `ssh` usually don't misinterpret the parameters passed to it. If your `ssh` is so broken that it mistakes `-f` for its own option, use `--` before the `command`. Try `ssh user@host -- rm -r -f /path`. The double dash tells it that remaining arguments are not part of `ssh` option.

Comment: "you should take a look on this to understand" ... No, you should edit and include only relevant information from that link in your Q. Questions on S.O. should be self-contained and not require reading posts on other sites OR multiple comments asking for clarifications. Finally, this really isn't a programming Q as defined for S.O. You should post such Qs to http://superuser.com . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter "[...] to understand my side", in that point I just knew that. I will edit the question to make some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no difference in them. You can verify it in the [source of `rm` (coreutils)](https://github.com/goj/coreutils/blob/rm-d/src/rm.c#L234).

They are independent options, setting these flags:

```
case 'f':
  x.interactive = RMI_NEVER;
  x.ignore_missing_files = true;
  prompt_once = false;
[...]
case 'r':
case 'R':
  x.recursive = true;
```

and the flags are effective later in the code. It is common way of parsing arguments in Linux/unix.